# helping needed in my Visual basic program

Tags: vb.net

i have a problem with my Visual Basic.net code

I am making "kind of" a child monitoring software that is able to record keystrokes and take screen shots, But i Have no idea how to Create a new .bmp file when it allready exsist.

```
 Try
        'the working area excludes all docked toolbars like taskbar, etc.
        Dim currentScreen = Screen.FromHandle(Me.Handle).WorkingArea

        'create a bitmap of the working area
        Using bmp As New Bitmap(currentScreen.Width, currentScreen.Height)

            'copy the screen to the image
            Using g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
                g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), currentScreen.Size)
            End Using

            'save the image
             'look for the file
            If IO.File.Exists(save1.Text) Then
                 'if exsist then add (2) to the filename
                bmp.Save(Save1.text + "(2)" + ".bmp")
              'done
            End If
            bmp.Save(Save1.Text)

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try


End Sub
```

As you can see the program checks if the bmp file already exists, if it does the program will generate new bmp file. For example: if file (whatever.bmp)  exists, then it will not overwrite it, instead it adds "(2)" in the file name exmp: (whatever(2).bmp).

So the problem is that i do not want to generate dozens of lines of code for just this function, I am looking for an automatic way to add the (2), (3),(4) or whatever to the filename if it already exists to prevent overwriting.

Sorry for my bad english :D

-Matt

Comment: Just a suggestion for code integrity, modify those "+" for "&".

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the class declaration initialize a variable where picture index will be stored:

```
Private picIndex As Long = 0
```

Then you could use `Threading.Interlocked.Increment` to increment the variable number:

```
bmp.Save(String.Format("{0} {1}.bmp", _
                       Save1.text, _
                       Threading.Interlocked.Increment(picIndex)))
```

If you are trying to write a generic procedure then you will consider to add inside the variable as `Static`

```
Public shared Sub MakeScreenshot(...)
    ...
    Static picIndex As Long = 0
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: what will happen, if the program is restarted? :)

Comment: @Vlad L I don't get what you are trying to mean, what would happen if application is restarted?

Comment: I mean that if you restart your application, the counter will be 0

Comment: Yes but since OP does not specified that if at application start the folder would be empty or full of previous saved files or whatever else...you know.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution you can increment the number and check if file exists. If not - save it.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Int32.MaxValue - 1
    Dim name As String = Save1.text + "(" + i + ").bmp"
    If Not File.Exists(name) Then
        bmp.Save(name)
            Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim counter as integer
counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("your image folder path")
bmp.Save(Save1.text & "(" & counter & ")" & ".bmp")
```